# Outlook crashes, when Outlook window shared on Teams call

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

At work on Teams calls, I often use the "Share Window" feature to share a window from Outlook (e.g. the meeting invitation, including the agenda). After approx 5 mins, Outlook crashes i.e. it hangs and becomes unresponsive, before Windows ask if I want to wait or close.

Outlook and Teams are otherwise stable individually. Team will happily share a window from Word for example - it's just this combination.

Office Version 2202. Teams Version 1.5.00.21668.

Comment: Try a full repair of Office and a repair of Teams. When I use Teams, it works fine here,

Comment: If the repair doesn't do it, or you can't do the repair, have your IT department look into it.  It might involve a reinstall of one or both.

Comment: Do you have [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) installed? IIRC it had a similar issue in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Do other user around you encounter the same issue?

And does this issue occur recently? If so, have you done any specific operations before that?

Please first confirm you have updated Outlook to the latest version. Agree with John and squillman, fixing Office/uninstalling and reinstalling Office/Teams are worth trying. In addition, as far as the Outlook client is concerned, it is suggested that you could try to **create a new profile**(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

If none of the above is valid,  it's suggested that you could try to use the [Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-e90bb691-c2a7-4697-a94f-88836856c72f) to check if there're any problems, which works by running tests to figure out what's wrong and offers the best solution for the identified problem.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.